# How to get list of running app in Android

Tags: android

I'm making an app like the image below and want to get all running app in the system, currently I use ActivityManager with API>21 and get runningAppProcesses but it just returns only my app in the result list. I try many other ways like: getRunningTasks,... but get the same result. Anyone have a better solution? Thanks so much for helping me!
(Described image here: https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Screenshot_2016-06-07-21-06-00.png)

Answer (score 1):

The methods you mention were deprecated because of privacy concerns.
The only substitute I know of is the [UsageStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager), which you can query to get events like [ACTIVITY_RESUMED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageEvents.Event#ACTIVITY_RESUMED) (An activity moved to foreground) or [ACTIVITY_STOPPED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageEvents.Event#ACTIVITY_STOPPED) (Activity became invisible).

It requires the [PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS)
*special* permission. You can not ask for it, you have to direct the user to the settings using [Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS).